# Descargar archivo PDF en Vue3

Tags: html5, vue.js

Lo que quiero lograr es que al darle click al botón "descargar cv" este descargue un archivo pdf que tengo alejado de manera local en mi proyecto, he intentado de diferentes maneras pero al parecer no lee la ruta donde se encuentra mi archivo, leí que lo debo de tener en la carpeta public y es allí donde lo tengo actualmente pero al darle click a descargar, obtengo un mensaje que dice "No se pudo descargar: no existe el archivo" anexo un poco del código que tengo hasta ahora, cualquier sugerencia o ayuda lo agradecería mucho.

```
<template>
 <div class="download-cv">
        <div class="btn"><a download="cv" href="../../public/cv.pdf">Descargar CV</a></div>
 </div>
</template>
```

El archivo pdf lo tengo almacenado en la carpeta public y se llama cv.pdf.
Gracias de ante mano.

Comment: el archivo debe estar dentro del root web (debes poder accesar a el mediante una dirección en tu navegador), si esta afuera no lo va a lograr encontrar... tendrías que implementar en un backend una lectura de disco a ram para despues brindar un archivo blob de descarga.

Comment: valida la situación que tienes y me comentas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buenas quiero compartir como he resuelto mi problema por si alguien se encuentra en esta situación.

1.- Primero en tu archivo index.html que se encuentra en tu carpeta public debes agregar en el head el link que accede a tu archivo, quedaría de la siguiente manera.

```
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
  **<link rel="pdf" href="<%= BASE_URL %>cv.pdf">**
  <title>
    <%= htmlWebpackPlugin.options.title %>
  </title>
</head>
```

2.- Ahora tu archivo pdf se debe encontrar en la raíz de tu carpeta public.

3.- Por ultimo el botón de descarga.

```
<a download="Darinel Cigarroa CV" href="/cv.pdf">Descargar CV</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

usando un botón

```
downloadCv() {
  const link = document.createElement('a');
  link.href = '/cv.pdf';
  link.setAttribute('download', 'cv.pdf');
  document.body.appendChild(link);
  link.click();
  document.body.removeChild(link);
}
```

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y explica brevemente el funcionamiento del código. Lee [answer].

Comment: El problema parece ser completamente otro.